# jsreport The specified executable is not a valid application for this OS platform

Tags: c#, asp.net, node.js, jsreport

I am using jsreport.embedded with my C# application, it works perfectly fine on my development PC is 64 bit windows 10 environment, but when I deployed the build to client PC which is running 32 bit windows 10, everything stopped working. What I did is manually replacing node.exe with 32bit node.exe (v0.10.29). BTW My Visual Studio Target Platform is AnyCPU. I am getting this Error Message on 32bit windows 10,

```
{
  "Message": "An error has occurred.",
  "ExceptionMessage": "The specified executable is not a valid application for this OS platform.",
  "ExceptionType": "System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception",
  "StackTrace": "   at System.Diagnostics.Process.StartWithCreateProcess(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)\r\n   at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start()\r\n   at jsreport.Embedded.EmbeddedReportingServer.StartWorker()\r\n   at jsreport.Embedded.EmbeddedReportingServer.d__1.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at REVOBackend.Services.JSReportPDFBase.\u0002.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at REVOBackend.Controllers.JSReportController.\u0005.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at REVOBackend.Controllers.JSReportController.\b.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskHelpersExtensions.d__3`1.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ApiControllerActionInvoker.d__0.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.d__5.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.d__5.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.d__0.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ActionFilterResult.d__2.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.d__1.MoveNext()"
}
```

Comment: Are you able to run the replaced node x32 node on the target machine? Please try to run in the target machine bin folder the following: `node jsreport-net-embedded\server.js --httpPort 2000` what does it print?

Comment: I deployed 32bit node.exe to the folder, I am able to run node on cmd but jsreport is not working, giving the same error message.

Comment: You run `node jsreport-net-embedded\server.js --httpPort 2000` and it gives the error *The specified executable...* just during the startup? Nothing else printed? And `node.exe` runs just fine? Maybe it is `phantomjs.exe` issue, try to find it in `jsreport-net-embedded` and run it.

Comment: Thanks For your reply, I followed your instruction, I got status up to "reporter initialized", but when I trigger my app api, it fails, it is successful on 64bit windows 10

Comment: I checked phantonjs.exe website, they have only one unified version for v1.9.8. any solution or any way to retrieve detailed error log ?

Comment: jsreport should write logs to `jsreport-net-embedded\logs`. Does html recipe based template work for you? If yes, try to run phantomjs from command line and see. It is possible they don't support winXP/win server 2003

Comment: My client is running on windows 10 32 bit, there is one guy who mentioned jsreport 32bit in the issue tracking. https://github.com/jsreport/jsreport/issues/75, he mentioned he has to install manually, but I do not know how.